# Comments are not displaying in wordpress 3.1

Tags: php, wordpress

Im running Wordpress 3.1 and its showing that there are comments (ie: 3 comments) but when you click into the single blog post they don't appear but the comment form appears.

Im not sure whether its a template issue or something's not correct in the functions.php.

I have the multi site function running for multiple blogs.

Anyone else having this problem and or have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be template issue, make sure that you have **comments.php** file present in your theme directory. You may want to copy from default theme too. The **functions.php** has nothing to do with that though.